# Fibonacci Heap that consolidates after every step

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, heaps, amortized-analysis

The lecturer of my graduate algorithms course suggested that, even if a Fibonacci Heap would consolidate its tree list after *every* operation (not just when doing *deleteMin()*), most operations would still have $\mathcal{O}(1)$ amortized complexity.

I've been trying to prove this, starting with the classical potential function $\phi := \#\text{trees} + 2\#\text{marked nodes}$, and managed to prove it for the *insert* operation. Here is a sketch:

Our heap is consolidated, so it contains trees of different ranks, which we can encode using a binary number $w$, where $w_i = 1$ iff we have a tree of rank $i \geq 0$. We count the bits of $w$ starting at $0$ from right to left. Let $l$ be the number of ones $w$ has at its tail; e.g. if $w = 101011$, then $l=2$. When inserting a new element into our heap, we can implement the required consolidation in just $l+1$ time (ignoring constants) by avoiding an iteration through the other $|w|-l$ trees. (This can be done by keeping an array $a$ of pointers where $a[i]$ is a pointer to the root of the tree of rank $i$.) If before the insertion we had $t$ trees, we'll now have $t'=t-l+1$ trees. Because the number of marked nodes does not change, this leads to $\Delta\phi = t'-t = -l+1$, and therefore the amortized running time is $(l+1) + \Delta\phi = 2 = \mathcal{O}(1)$ time.

Then I tried doing a similar proof for the *decreaseKey()* operation, but here I started having problems. My issue is that the cascading cut can introduce trees of various sizes into the tree list, and the consolidation that follows seems to be hard to upper bound, s.t. we get $\mathcal{O}(1)$ amortized time at the end.

I would appreciate any help to find this proof.